How to fine-tune an ensemble-level hyper-parameter in the following problem?
I have a relatively small dataset of 4000 instances. I aim to perform classification using an ensemble approach. My ensemble consists of 5 different classifiers and I have an ensemble-level hyper-parameter S.
I plan to follow the steps below to train and evaluate my ensemble model:

Split the initial dataset into 70% training, 15% validation, and 15% test.
Train each classifier on the training dataset using 5-fold cross-validation (in each case, train on 4 folds and evaluate accuracy on 1 hold-out fold).
Based on the average accuracy of each classifier across all 5 hold-out folds (i.e., across the whole training dataset), determine weights per classifier. In the weight calculation formula there is an ensemble-level hyper-parameter S, initialized to a random value within [0,1].
In order to fine-tune S, evaluate the performance of the ensemble model on the validation dataset, using the classifier weights calculated in the previous step. Change the value of S, recalculate the classifier weights based on the new value of S, and re-evaluate the performance of the ensemble model on the validation dataset, and repeat until the ensemble performance is maximized or a specific number of iterations is reached.
After determining the final value of S and the corresponding classifier weights, evaluate the performance of the ensemble model on the test dataset (unseen data).

My concern is that the fine-tuning of hyper-parameter S is performed using the whole validation dataset in each iteration. Would it be more appropriate to split the validation dataset, for example, into 3 subsets (considering that my dataset is small) and for each value of S evaluate the average performance of the ensemble across all 3 subsets? Or my initial approach as described above is adequate (considering the small size of the dataset)?
